# '101: Network is unreachable' error when I ran sudo apt-get update on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04

I launched an EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 server. It is contained in a VPC which is connected to a private VPN. To SSH into the server, you have to connect to that VPN which is also on AWS before having access to the server. After setting everything up and started configuring the server I discovered that sudo apt-get update did not install any update and I got the error below:

> ubuntu@private-ip:~$ sudo apt-get update
>   Err:1 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
>     Could not connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (IP), connection timed out [IP]
>   Err:2 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
>     Unable to connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP]
>   Err:3 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
>     Unable to connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP]
>   Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
>     Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP]
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (IP), connection timed out [IP]
>   W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP]
>   W: Failed to fetch http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP]
>   W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to security.ubuntu.com:80 (). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP]
>   W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I tried to install apache too but got a similar error. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: You don't have a route to the Internet.  Who set up the system?  They missed a step.

Comment: A colleague did. Any idea what went wrong please?